# Email received in the form of "Message clipped" using Email API + Meteor 1.5

Tags: meteor, gmail

I am using Email API with Meteor 1.5. Below is my creation code of sending an HTML Template as an Email.

**Meteor Method:**

```
'sendRegEmail'(username, email, id){
    var css = Assets.getText('bootstrap.min.css');
    SSR.compileTemplate('layout', Assets.getText('layout.html'));
    Template.layout.helpers({
      getDocType: function() {
        return "<!DOCTYPE html>";
      }
    });
    SSR.compileTemplate('new_registration', Assets.getText('app_newregistration.html'));
    var myData = {
      'username' : username,
      'userId' : id,
      'email' : email
    };
    var html_string = SSR.render('layout', {
      css: css,
      template: "new_registration",
      data: myData
    });
    this.unblock();
    Email.send({
      to: email,
      from: "Admin <info@domain.com>",
      subject: "New Registration, User ID :"+id,
      html: html_string,
    });
  }
```

The problem is that the mail is received at the user's end, but it show below format inside mail. why it shows **message clipped**?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not related to Meteor or email package.
Its related to gmail, if your html document size greater than 102kb then gmail will clip your message.

For more info.
http://www.emailmonks.com/blog/email-design/avoid-gmail-clipping/